# Uploading ASP.NET 3.5 website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a website writen in ASP.NET and C#.

The site works when run locally, however I don't have any experience with uploading. Recently I got a free hosting package from [somee.com](http://somee.com) and am currently trying to upload it.

Basically, the pages that don't require database connection work, the ones that do don't. So, I've created a database on somee.com and attached my database to that. I've tested it through somee.com control panel with a couple of querys and it works fine.

So I believe the site is uploaded correctly, database works also. I figure it must be a connection problem. In my codebehind, every database connection uses the web.config connection string. I believe there is a problem somewhere in the web.config file, specifically with the connection string.

I have replaced my connection string with the connection string generated by the somee.com control panel which is:

```
<add name="feniks_dbConnectionString"
connectionString="workstation id=SQLEXPRESS003.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=*;pwd=*;data source=SQLEXPRESS003.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=SQLEXPRESS003"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I've marked my id and pass with *. I keep getting the same error, you can try it yourself on http://aspsitetest.somee.com/index.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Error on page not about sql-connect  - it writes about wrong web.config

search for duplicate:

```
There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined
```

If the same web.config works on local machine, maybe you use another version of IIS.

Comment: how did you get that??
when I try to run it it gives me : "Server Error in '/' Application.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: hm, I've just clicked on your link, but now, you right, it's another error.